# Was there ever a cannibalistic butcher/meat pie/restaurant... shop?

Tags: nutrition, economics, behavior

Has there ever been a real case of [Sweeney Todd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweeney_Todd)'s (without the musical of course)?

As it seems a really non cost effective way of running a shop, similar stories pop up in few different cultures (as far as I have been able to verify), but with no actual real backing.

Comment: Can you provide notability for this? Does anyone actually believe there are cannibalistic butchers?

Comment: @Skilvvz : Can you please change the tag to Urban-Legends? Non of the tags have anything with the intended motivation. It is an archipycal idea that has surfaced enough that movies have been made for it. If people can question the cryptids why not roots of Urban Legends like Sweeny Tod? Thank you

Comment: urban-legends is a blacklisted tag, as it is a meta tag and also it already presumes falseness. See http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/486/burninating-the-conspiracy-theories-tag

Comment: @Sklivvz : Do you think it is better to delete this post or modify it? if the latter any hints on what to aim for?

Comment: I didn't know that Sweeny Todd was an actual urban legend! I thought it was just a musical/movie... I've added a link to your question.

Comment: Yeah - there's been an urban legend sweeney todd was an actual person for more 100 years. Wikipedia gives a good overview of this IMO
 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweeney_Todd#Alleged_historical_basis

Comment: It's also notable that the Crime Library reports the Urban Legend as Fact, so i think the claim's pretty notable :)           

http://www.crimelibrary.com/serial_killers/weird/todd/index_1.html

Comment: Exactly: it’s *not* a cost-effective way (stiffs don’t come by easily). Why should anyone try it?

Comment: [Soylent Green](http://mimg.ugo.com/201008/54829/cuts/soylent-cooking_786x786.jpg)

Comment: @Skilvvz : Long before I heard of Sweeney Todd, read a story in an old folk tales book in a different culture in completely unrelated part of the world. Every now and then came across a similar setup in stories/moies/urban legends/boogieman kind of stories. Wondered weather  it was just a mime working acroess cultures or some type of behaviourial outlier in population that happened for real.

Comment: If you have a body to dispose of and a meat grinder adding parts to a sausage mix would seem pretty ideal.  If you read Upton Sinclair's 'The Jungle' it includes descriptions of people who would lose digits and limbs into a meat grinder that was just ground up and sold.

Comment: And don't forget [Delicatessen](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101700/)

Comment: http://www.warriors.egympie.com.au/cannibalism.html mentions "Skull **trading** (after meat extraction) by the Maoris of New Zealand in the 1800’s"  is that close enough?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seem to have been several people rumoured to be serving human meat down the years, but some such as [Fritz Haarman](http://www.spiegel.de/international/zeitgeist/0,1518,654732-6,00.html), never had the accusation proved (although the brutal murders were).

However theres a few items which seem pretty well established of human meat being provided to unknowing customers in a butcher shop—for example.

The first I found was Adloph Luetgert, which seems [to be a well established story.](http://www.alchemyofbones.com/who/luetgertfamily/adolph.htm) This chap only did it once though as a way to dispose of his wife's body

More recently the there was [this story](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/human-flesh-on-sale-in-moldova-680055.html), of human meat being sold in a shop in Moldova. Supposedly though - they got the [body parts from a local clinic.](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/world/europe/1256023.stm)

The last story indicates a little bit of the problem with the idea of a demon butcher who slaughters people for sale, as in that tale they were illegally using parts from a clinic.

To provide a constant supply of meat for your shop by other methods would be clearly difficult.

I guess you would not get more than 40-50kg or so meat from each person killed (a Hog tends to make about [70% of its body mass into meat apparently](http://www.askthemeatman.com/yield_on_hog.htm), and I would be surprised if your yield from a corpse was greater).

Even a slowish shop would get through that in a week I guess (can't find average for this), so you would need to kill a person a week or two to keep your small shop adequately stocked.

Such a murder spree would be unlikely to be sustainable long term, if you are in a country with a police force.